# Fetching data from many-to-many relationships

Tags: mysql, database, many-to-many

I want to fetch the title from book table and the subject name from subject table for all the books of a certain author

Here is the tables relationships

[image]

[image]

I have tried to select the title and the subject from the tables but I can't get it to work with the many to many relationship

```
SELECT book_title,subject_name FROM book,subject WHERE $subject_ID = subject_ID INNER JOIN book_author ON author_ID = '$author_ID'
```

I thought about making two separate queries, if someone could help me on that I would be really glad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT book_title, subject_name
FROM Book
INNER JOIN Book_Author ON Book.book_ISBN = Book_Author.book_ISBN
INNER JOIN Author ON Book_Author.author_ID = Author.author_ID
INNER JOIN Subject ON Subject.subject_ID = Book.subject_ID
WHERE author_lastname = [whatever];
```

And nice job posting the model :)

Edit to match the exact need:

```
SELECT book_title, subject_name
FROM Book
INNER JOIN Book_Author ON Book.book_ISBN = Book_Author.book_ISBN
INNER JOIN Subject ON Subject.subject_ID = Book.subject_ID
WHERE author_ID = '11';
```

And by the way, you're having an `"Column 'author_ID' in where clause is ambiguous"` because this column appears both in Book_Author and Author. That's why you have to prefix it with the table name :)

Comment: I'm trying to use this with an author ID because I need to use a unique author and this is my query: SELECT book_title, subject_name
FROM Book
INNER JOIN Book_Author ON Book.book_ISBN = Book_Author.book_ISBN
INNER JOIN Author ON Book_Author.author_ID = Author.author_ID
INNER JOIN Subject ON Subject.subject_ID = Book.subject_ID
WHERE author_ID = '11'

Comment: This is the error I get:  "Column 'author_ID' in where clause is ambiguous"

Comment: If you are working with the author ID you don't need to join with the Author table. Remove this join or rewrite the end of your query with WHERE Author.author_ID = '11' :)